# ejabberd return type of the hook handler

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-hooks

Is it necessary for the hook handler to return the type of the value (ie. return value type) as specified in the https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The type in the documentation is only provided for guidance about what to return. You do not have to return it.

Comment: Does this mean all the handlers(in case of multiple handlers listening to single event) will get the same arguments irrespective of the return value from the handler ?.   In other words the return value of one handler is not passed as argument to another handler. Is this correct ?